# Coalescing GCD file system events

Tags: macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class that implements a file-monitoring service to detect when a file I am interested in has been changed by something other than my application. I use the standard technique of opening the file (with the `O_EVTONLY` flag) and binding the file descriptor to a Grand Central Dispatch source of type `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE`. When I get an event, I notify my main thread with `NSNotificationCenter`'s `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` which calls an observer in my app delegate. So far so good. It works great. But, in general, if the triggering event is an attributes change (i.e. the `DISPATCH_VNODE_ATTRIB` flag is set on return from `dispatch_source_get_data()`) then I usually get two closely-spaced events. The behaviour is easily exhibited if I `touch(1)` the object I am monitoring. I hypothesise this is due to the file's mtime and atime being set non-atomically although I can't verify this. This can lead to spurious notifications being sent to my observer and this raises the possibility of race conditions etc.

What is the best way of dealing with this? I thought of storing a timestamp for the last event received and only sending a notification if the current event is later than this timestamp by some amount (a few tens of milliseconds?) Does this sound like a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ever escape the "race condition" in this situation, because the notification of your GCD event source in your process is not synchronous with the other process's modification of the underlying file. So, no matter what, you must *always* be tolerant of the possibility that the change you're being notified for could already be "gone."

As for coalescing, do whatever makes sense for your app. There are two obvious strategies. You can act immediately on a received event, and then drop subsequent events received in some time window on the floor, or you can delay every event for some time period during which you will drop other events for the same file on the floor. It really just depends on what's more important, acting quickly, or having a higher likelihood of a quiescent state (knowing that you can never be *sure* things are quiescent.)

The only thing I would add is to suggest that you do all your coalescence *before* dispatching anything to the main thread. The main thread has things like tracking loops, etc that will make it harder to get time-based coalescing right in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the first option by comparing the time an event was received (stored in my monitor class) with the previous one and ignoring it if it was in the window. There is some additional weirdness going on - only certain files give the double event, and it can be delayed up to 2 seconds. Also, if I display a modal alert, that blocks everything and so the second event is deferred until after it returns. I throw away anything received while in my notification handler and extend the timeout window after the alert is dismissed. It works, but I'm not overjoyed about it.